# Example of real function with two variables that is differentiable at exactly one point

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I had an idea for function $f(x,y)= 0$ if both $x,y$ are rational numbers, else
$f(x,y)=x^2 + y^2$.

I've managed to show that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$, but I don't know how to prove that $f$  isn't differentiable at points $(x,y)$ different from $(0,0)$.

Comment: Where is your function continuous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$ and $(x,y)\notin\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$, we can choose rational points $(x_{n},y_{n})$ such that $(x_{n},y_{n})\rightarrow(x,y)$.

If $f$ is differentiable at $(x,y)$, it is continuous at that point, but then $f(x_{n},y_{n})=0\rightarrow f(x,y)=x^{2}+y^{2}>0$, a contradiction.

If $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$ but $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$, we take irrational points $(x_{n},y_{n})$ such that $(x_{n},y_{n})\rightarrow(x,y)$.

Again $f$ being continuous at that point, $f(x_{n},y_{n})\rightarrow f(x,y)=0$, on the other hand, $f(x_{n},y_{n})=x_{n}^{2}+y_{n}^{2}\rightarrow x^{2}+y^{2}$, we deduce that $(x,y)=(0,0)$, a contradiction.

Comment: This should be edited. It's a long run-on sentence and  $(x_n,y_n)\to (0,0)$ is a typo.